# Is glycerol/glycerin soluble in ethanol?

Tags: homework, solubility, alcohols

As titled, I wish to know if glycerol/glycerin is soluble in ethanol (not soluble, slightly soluble, very soluble)

Comment: Since this is homework, you should give your opinion and reason. We will then give you information.

Comment: I imagine that it is indeed soluble, since ethanol is weakly polar and glycerol is also polar. However i just want to be sure of this, as ethanol is, as said, weakly polar.

Comment: I did a search with Google with the words "glycerol ethanol solubility" and came up with this: http://www.sbioinformatics.com/design_thesis/Glycerol/Glycerol_-2520Properties&uses.pdf

Answer (score 1):

As [LDC3](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/users/4934/ldc3) indicated above [here](http://www.sbioinformatics.com/design_thesis/Glycerol/Glycerol_-2520Properties&uses.pdf) it states that "Glycerol is **completely soluble** in water and alcohol." So, this is correct, as also indicated [here](http://www.dow.com/optim/optim-advantage/physical-properties/solubility.htm).

Now, for the reason this happens it is most likely because of its 3 hydroxyl groups ($-OH$) and the fact that it is a polar molecule.