# Does sorbitol dissolve in ethanol?

Tags: organic-chemistry, solubility, alcohols

I know Sorbitol, $\ce{C_6H_14O_6}$ $$\ce {C(OH)H_2 (C(OH)H)_4C(OH)H_2}$$is soluble in water however I did not have much luck finding out whether or not it is soluble in ethanol. My guess is that it isn't however I am not so sure.

Is Sorbitol soluble in ethanol?

Comment: Did you see [this](http://gcse2011.srcict.com/en-us/Paper.aspx?id=17)?

Comment: The case is very similar as in http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/19598/is-glycerol-glycerin-soluble-in-ethanol

Comment: Hallo Klaus, das ist ja toll! Bei den Grünen ist die Messung von ein paar Löslichkeiten also Wissenschaft?

Comment: @Georg I see that with less sarcasm ;) True, the measurements won't qualify for a publication in *J. Phys. Chem.*, but sometimes it's exactly the fundamental data one is looking for. No fancy interpretation, just the boring data, a well-described, reproducible setup and a careful experimenter. This is even more true if a survey covers a whole series of compounds under identical conditions (which admittedly isn't the case here).

Answer (score 2):

Sorbitol's solubility in ethanol seems to be very temperature dependent according to the Merck Index$^{[1]}$

> Freely sol in water (up to 83%); sol in methanol, isopropanol, butanol, cyclohexanol, phenol, acetone, acetic acid, dimethylformamide, pyridine, acetamide solutions; practically insoluble in most other org solvents; **quite soluble in hot alcohol, sparingly soluble in cold alcohol**

1) *O'Neil, M.J. (ed.). The Merck Index - An Encyclopedia of Chemicals, Drugs, and Biologicals. Whitehouse Station, NJ: Merck and Co., Inc., 2006., p. 1498*